# how to multiply two n digit numbers assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to do a multiplication between two numbers without a digit limit in assembly 8086. It's easy to do a sum of two numbers of n digits because I separate the number into small ones that fit the registers size and only check the carry flag, but how can I do a multiplication. Is it too slow to do a multiplication using consecutive sums with big numbers like 20 digits each one?

Comment: When you are multiplying a row by column, each partial product (in dx:ax) is small enough to be added with 0xffff. (FFFF * FFFF == FFFE0001) Thus there can be a carry between ax->dx, but not from dx to the next digit.

Comment: How is your digits stored in memory and what base?